# How to get the log of SharePoint workflow mail details in a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SharePoint designer workflow for sending mail in my application. Is there any possibility to get the following details as a log in SharePoint list. Details are :

1. From address
2. To address
3. Main sending time
4. Subject of mail

Answer (score 1):

You can do that. First, create these fields in the list.
Then, in the workflow you can add another action just below the email sending action. In that action (Set Field in Current Item) you just write to the given field whatever info you require.
Alternatively, you can write to SharePoint Workflow History any event you think is necessary. This is also very useful if you're debugging a problem in the workflow and you don't know where exactly it fails.
What I do is I add a log line BEFORE and AFTER ***any action*** in the workflow and write this log line to workflow history. The action for this in the Actions menu is called "Log to History List"
You can then access history list by clicking on the workflow instance for your list item. If you do not see the workflow column in the list, go to list settings and click on the view you are using. Then, check the workflow column and save the view. Now you'll be able to click on the workflow instance and see the history.
And finally, there is a "hidden" list in every site called Workflow History.
You can access it by directly typing its URL:
"http://yoursitename/Lists/workflow%20history/AllItems.aspx"
Here you can follow all workflows that ran within the scope of this site.
Good luck!